# Defective Transformer Replacement

Tags: power-supply, transformer, tv, replacement, component-values

I've been working on repairing a TV psu, and discovered that the transformer in it is faulty (reading O.L. on every combination of pins except for diagonal in ohms mode on the DMM)

I've been looking for more information on the specific transformer, but haven't been able to find anything. I'd like to source a replacement.

What would you guys suggest I should do to find a working alternative? Since I can't measure anything on it, since it's dead, and the internet has basically no info on it...?

(Label on top of the transformer: "PFCV-DP5062 DCGM 0634(02) C")

[image: Pins on the bottom]

[image: Text on top]

Comment: It looks like the PFC inductor. Why do you think this has failed? These items are unlikely to fail. Diagnosing psu problems can be tricky as the PFC and main switcher sections can be inter-related.

Comment: refer to the TV schematic ... it may have some info about the transformer

Comment: Also note that it is most likely a custom part and not easily sourced except from other dead boards or replacement boards. What is the measured voltage on the main filter capacitor? If it is 320V the PFC section isn’t operating. Should be 340-380V.

Comment: Why do you think it is even supposed to be a transformer? Post photo of the power supply board from where you detached it.

Comment: This question has more information, but it was automatically deleted due to it being off-topic: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/595583/tv-power-supply-repair?noredirect=1#comment1563586_595583

Comment: I think it has failed, because I removed most components from the circuit to test them individually using a multimeter and this was the only one of the parts that I've currently taken off that seemed to have readings that were completely off... (O.L) As for the reason of it failing... No idea, the only other strange thing I have noticed thus far is that the 150microFarad cap is reading 130microFarad on the DMM, and some other capacitors are as well reading a bit lower than their intended values.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a PFC transformer for grid isolation and AC to DC active PFC control on a Philips TV.

https://www.ebay.fr/itm/233758363908?mkevt=1&mkcid=1&mkrid=709-53476-19255-0&campid=5338722076&toolid=10001

The DC should go on the center tap secondary with dual Nch switches with PWM on each branch.

Comment: Thanks for the product link Tony, I wasn't able to find that one. As for the other part of your answer (and I'm sorry for providing incomplete information) but the center tap on the secondary side was not connected to the circuit at all.

Comment: If it is just an inductor, be sure of your measurements.

Comment: To provide more info: every combination of pins gives me an O.L reading on OHMS mode on the DMM, except for diagonal pins. One set of diagonal pins gives 0.10ohms, the other diagonal gives 0.40ohms.

Comment: The middle pin of the three pins is not connected. From what you describe, it looks like the device is ok. As I said before, it is unlikely to fail. Does the tv have a standby power supply? There’s usually a led that blinks when you press a button on the remote control. If that power supply fails, nothing else will work.

Comment: The low DCR is high AC impedance with at least 1mH per ohm

Comment: The tv has just one power supply, which is the one I'm currently working on. It has a 3.3vs rail, which I interpreted as 3.3V standby. This rail (and all other voltage rails) are not outputting any voltage, and therefore the light on the tv doesn't turn on at all.

Comment: I couldn't find the issue, so I started labeling everything and desoldering all the components, check them all individually and if they work reconnect them. All parts that I've checked up till this point (most large components from the primary stage) seem fine, except for some capacitors reading a bit lower than their intended value. This transformer was also giving a different reading from what I expected, but I guess my expectations were just wrong then. As far as I could see, there is no power at all in the secondary stage, so I guess I just need to tear down the rest of the primary side...

Comment: you must post the TV model to find the schematic . just as I did here https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpJ6K.png

Comment: The psu model is DPS-188AP, tv model nr. = 32PF7331

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJVfG.png